# How to use an external jquery plugin with Script#?

Tags: jquery-plugins, script#

How can I use an external jquery plugin with Script# 0.7? Is there a tool to convert any jquery plugin to equivalent c# code? Or we have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's usually a better use of one's time to include the plugin as-is (in it's JavaScript form), and then prepare an imported type in Script# for exposing the plugin's functionality to the rest of Script#.

I don't know if there is a shortcut approach in Script# when dealing specifically with jQuery plugins, but what I've quickly done in the past is something like the following:

```
// Import my plugin "Foo"
[Imported]
[IgnoreNamespace]
public class jQueryWithFoo : jQueryObject
{
    private jQueryWithFoo () { }

    [ScriptName("foo")]
    public void FooInit() { }

    [ScriptName("foo")]
    public void FooMethod(string method) { }

    [ScriptName("foo")]
    public void FooMethodWithOptions(string method, Dictionary options) { }
}
```

Then to use the plugin on an object you just cast to your imported type:

```
// grab my div and cast to my plugin type
jQueryWithFoo myDiv = (jQueryWithFoo)jQuery.Select("#myDiv");

// use the plugin
myDiv.FooInit();
myDiv.FooMethod("toggle");
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your exact code, the following might also be appropriate:

```
jQuery.Select("#myDiv").Plugin<jQueryWithFoo>().FooInit();
```

This is useful if you have multiple plugins you want to use, and use the fluent-API pattern that you would in regular jQuery. Example:

```
jQuery.Select("#myDiv").
    Plugin<jQueryFoo>().FooInit().
    Plugin<jQueryBar>().SomeBarMethod();
```